# calculate timing in webBrowser.DocumentCompleted

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can we calculate timing? I mean when pressed click it's should start(time) and when finished load page than stop. when you searching in google, its shown you a time how long it takes.

```
/*
foreach (string bug in bugs)
{
    webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
    webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("product").SetAttribute("value", product);
    webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("version").SetAttribute("value", version);
    webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("commit").InvokeMember("click");

    //Need code to wait for page to load before continuing.
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use StopWatch classe to measure time look at the following example

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(10000);// here your code
    stopWatch.Stop();
    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
 }
}
```